# Performance Optimization for LINQ query in property getter

Tags: c#, performance, linq

So I have a class which models a `Sale` made in a store. The `Sale` class has a `List` of `Payment`. The sale class always has a property called `PointsPaid` which  uses LINQ to find the Sum of the payment amounts which are paid with loyalty points. This is what the class look likes.

```
public class Sale
{
    private List<Payment> Payments {get;set;}

    public decimal PointsPaid
    {
        get
        {
            return Payments.Where(p => p.PaymentType == PaymentType.Points)
                           .Sum(p => p.Amount) * LoyaltyRate
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a way to achieve the same thing for `PointsPaid` without having to execute a LINQ query each time I want to get the amount. I've never had to deal with optimising performance but this is for a real-world client.

Each `Sale` object would likely only ever one `Payment` so I'm also not sure if there will be a massive performance drain anyway.

Comment: maintain a `public decimal PointsPaid {get;set;}` propertie, every time you change Payments

Comment: You should bother for that only if you encounter real performance-problems and you know for sure that those are caused by that code, which is best done by **measuring**. Otherwise you overptimize your code and make it hard to read and to understand for a few nano-seconds. Having said this you *could* cache the result, but if it really safes you much time depends on how often you change the list and how often you call that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have full control over this list, it can't be modified from outside. So provide methods to add or remove payments and calculate the value there:

```
public class Sale
{
    private List<Payment> Payments {get;set;}       // initialize in constructor
    private decimal _sumPointsAmount;
    public decimal LoyaltyRate { get; private set; } // set via constructor

    public decimal PointsPaid => _sumPointsAmount * LoyaltyRate;

    public void AddPayment(Payment p)
    {
        Payments.Add(p);
        if (p.PaymentType == PaymentType.Points)
            _sumPointsAmount += p.Amount;
    }
    public bool RemovePayment(Payment p)
    {
        bool removed = Payments.Remove(p);
        if(removed && p.PaymentType == PaymentType.Points)
            _sumPointsAmount -= p.Amount;
        return removed;
    }
}
```